# Difference between the given generic functions?

Tags: java, generics

Considering the two functions:

```
public static void myFunction(List<?> list);

public static <T> void myFunction(List<T> list);
```

Please explain why we have included `<T>` before `myFuction`, and what does it signify?

Comment: Your second case will not compile. You probably mean `public static <T> void  myFunction(List<T> list);` (`<T>` was placed before return type).

Comment: Here is the [official tutorial about generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). The relevant items are "generic methods" and "wildcards".

Answer (score 1):

1. When you use `<?>` you are telling the virtual machine that you don't
   know what type of object will be in the List, could one type could
   be more than one type. `List<?>` is the equivalent of `List` from
   previous 1.4 Java version when you could add to a list any type of
   object and there was no constraint on that.
2. When you use `<T>` you are defining a generic method. You are telling
   the compiler that the `List<T>` is a list of objet of type `T`, which
   will determined from the call to the method, but you enforce that
   all object from List are of the same type, `T`. You include `<T>` before
   the the function name to specify that you are defining a generic
   method, and the compiler to know that `T` should be treated as a type
   and not as variable.

Comment: You should use backticks ( ` ) when writing out generics, or else the site will treat them as unrecognized/unallowed HTML tags and strip them out.

Comment: Np! And while I'm here, a small nit: in neither case do you tell the virtual machine anything -- all of that info is erased by the time the JVM runs. You're giving the information to the Java-to-bytecode compiler (javac or equivalent).

Comment: you are right, I intended to refer to the compiler :). thanks again.

Comment: What is the meaning of writing <T> before void ?

Comment: @PrateekJoshi It just declares that `T` is the name of a generic parameter. You can think of it as "for some type T". If you haven't read the generics tutorial, I would recommend it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/